# double background, one background repeat from the middle - css3

Tags: html, css

I have a double background with CSS3, I want the second background, repeat from the middle of the screen to the bottom (not from top).

http://es.tinypic.com/r/2s6x5w8/8

This is my css

```
body {
  background: url('../img/carbon_fibre.png'), url('../img/carbon_fibre_blue.png');
  background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
  background-position: center left, left top;
}
```

Some body knows how can I resolve this issue?

Thnaks, Christian

Comment: You can't. If a background has to be repeat on Y axis, he'll be repeat both ways.

Comment: Isn't scaling an option for you? That might be easier, especially in CSS3. Otherwise you could make divs with a lower z-index than the rest of your page to make this work.

Comment: This is CSS3, what's the solution?

Comment: Nobody knows the solution? I'm trying it, and the background's repeat both ways.

Comment: @user3455405 Please use `@RoXaS` next time so i get notified of your responses.  If scaling is an option then in CSS3: `background-size: 100% 100%; ` this should resize the background to fit your browser viewport.

Comment: thank you very much, but I don't want to scale!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with 2 backgrounds, @Aliassse is absolutely right.

The only way that you can get that effect is with a pseudo element.

CSS

```
body {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/50/50);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

body:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/40/40);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aesEE/)

Comment: Thanks @Aliassse. I hope that I can do it with pseudoelement, but I'll do just in one elemenThanks a lot man!